# Determine if certain parts of an RGB image are colored or grayscale using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to determine if certain parts of an RGB image are colored or grayscale, using python, opencv and numpy libraries. To be more spesific, in an RGB image I determine face locations using neural networks and when that image contains printed photos I would like to find out if the face location in that image is grayscale or colored.

[image: an example picture for the task mentioned earlier]

What I tried so far:

```
            red_average = np.average(rgb_image_crop[:,:,0])
            green_average = np.average(rgb_image_crop[:,:,1])
            blue_average = np.average(rgb_image_crop[:,:,2])

            highest_distance = max(abs(red_average-green_average), abs(red_average-blue_average), abs(green_average-blue_average))
            if highest_distance> 15:
                print("this crop is colored")
            else:
                print("this crop is grayscale")
```

After finding the location of faces, faces are cropped and named "rgb_image_crop". I basically split the R, G, B channels using numpy and took their averages separately. My logic was that grayscale images would have R, G, B pixel values close to each other compared to colored images and this method worked with average performance.

But I was wondering is there a more sophisticated approach than this with higher success hopefully? I looked through other questions, but everyone was just asking to determine if an image file is B/W or RGB.

**Edit after concluding the results:**
I have tried various methods in computer vision and then tried training CNN classifier using a dataset I created. Apparently CNN networks cannot learn colors much but mostly they learn textures and results were really disappointing. I trained a Darknet YOLOV4 based classifier and tests with real life examples failed to give satisfactory outcomes. Mark's suggestion has been the most stable one and after that the one I mentioned in my question. I will try to implement Mark's solution using hardware acceleration and make it use less CPU resources.

Comment: Off the top of my head, how about just trying to convert the cropped image to grayscale and use, say MSE(Mean Squared Error) function to determine if the cropped image was initially grayscale?

Comment: convert to YUV, consider U and V channels. -- "considering" means applying statistics (min/max, stddev, ...) -- if you convert to HSV or similar, Saturations can become ridiculous on dark points, and then you'd have to look at Value too, so maybe don't use HSV

Comment: Just crop the part you want to test and check if the 3 channels are equal by doing a difference between pairs of channels (or just check if the means of the 3 channels are equal)

Comment: @sai Thank you for your reply, I tried what you suggested, the results were successful  on average. But it wasn't as stable as the method I first mentioned in the question. The differences between colored and grayscale pictures were not so distinct, this became apparent with dark skin African faces especially.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Your suggestion is quite confusing, could you elaborate on that a bit more? I don't understand how converting to YUV would help me find out if the cropped picture is grayscale, isn't converting to grayscale a better idea?

Comment: if a pixel is gray in an RGB image then R=G=B

Comment: @DrBwts Since its not a perfect grayscale crop, r g b channels are not equal, but just close to each other.

Comment: Maybe a simple cnn based classifier might do the trick and have you gone through this article https://www.imageeprocessing.com/2017/07/image-classification-black-and-white.html ?

Comment: @sai A friend also suggested this idea, but I told him CNNs usually don't learn colors but just textures. But since you also mentioned it, I will give it a try.
After I create the dataset and arrange the classifier network, I will train and test the model, then write the results here.

Comment: You've chosen a rather unfortunate example image as the greys have a marked blue tone to them which means they don't actually show up as grey. Try running a *"Colour Picker"* tool over the man's face and you'll see what I mean. If you don't have one on your OS, you can use https://pinetools.com/image-color-picker

Comment: Mark, actually the example is very close to the task's actual possible cases. To be more specific, the original task is to determine if a face seen from our embedded camera is fake or real. So far I have deployed a pretty successful neural network that does the job accurately. But the network starts to act weird when it sees grayscale printed face images, while it has no problem with colored images and real faces. Therefore, I decided to determine if the face found from camera is grayscale or colored, if the face is grayscale I will conclude it is fake, ignoring the neural network's decision.

Comment: So far I have tried computer vision and CNN classifiers to get an accurate result, CNN didn't work well (since mostly they don't really learn colors, but textures in images), so I am applying computer vision solutions using numpy. PTP solution you offered and the average taking I initially showed in the question are most stable ones so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Numpy *peak-to-peak* across the 3rd dimension to get difference between smallest and largest RGB value at each pixel location. Then threshold that and count the outliers:

```
RGBrange = np.ptp(im, axis=2)
coloured = RGBrange > 10
```

You might also get some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218331/2836621).

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to research your old answers. I tried your suggestion as:
                RGB_range = np.ptp(img_spoof, axis=2)
                colored_ptp = RGB_range > 15
                colored_ptp = np.count_nonzero(colored_ptp) #the higher the colored_pth, more likely it is colored crop.

The results are more stable than my initially proposed idea. Currently I am experimenting with a CNN model to compare the results. After I have all the results, I will let you know which solution worked out the best.

Answer (score 1):

How about finding the max difference in every pixel of the cropped image and then taking the STD of them. With the gray scaled image, that value must be small compared with colored ones.

Comment: I think your suggestion will just determine if the cropped image consists of mostly one color, since standard deviation will just show us if the difference between RGB channels has changed throughout the image.